# AS3 Error #1009

Tags: timer

Please Help me, check this code :

This is output :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at Bechanodroid_LatihanPendahuluan_fla::MainTimeline/tick1()[Bechanodroid_LatihanPendahuluan_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:21]
>       at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

this is my code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var countDownInc:Number = 1;
var totalSecs = 10;
var countDownSecs = totalSecs;

timer.text = countDownSecs;
var time:Timer = new Timer(countDownInc*1000);

time.start();
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,tick);
function tick(e:TimerEvent):void{
    if(countDownSecs==0){
        time.stop();
        score+=0;
        nextPertanyaan();
        countDownSecs=totalSecs;
    }else{
        countDownSecs=countDownSecs-countDownInc;
        timer.text=countDownSecs;
    }
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);

Change it for this:

e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,tick);